# What is the best way to create a line graph in R ggplot2 for a dataframe containing 2 replicates per sample

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph

I have been playing around for ages trying to figure out the best way to manipulate a small dataframe into a format that can be used in ggplot to create a data frame based on the average of each condition with error bars.

This is is the dataframe:

```
 Dilution A2T2.R1 A2T2.R2 X293T.R1 X293T.R2 TZMbl.R1 TZMbl.R2
1       10       1       1        1        1        1        1
2       40       1       1        1        1        1        1
3      160       1       1        1        1        1        1
4      640       1       1        1        1       36       33
5     2560     102     101       98       98       80       78
6    10240     100     101       97       97       97       99
7    40960      99      92       98       98       98       93
8   163840      99      97       99       98       99      100
```

There are three different samples, A2T2, 293T and TZMbl, each with 2 replicates (R1 and R2). I want to plot them on a line graph with connected lines but plot the average of each of the replicates with standard deviation or standard error bars. I want the vlaue to be plotted on the Y axis and the dilution on the X axis.

My main issue has been getting this into a format that can be used to a) calculate stats and b) be used for ggplot.

I have been trying reshape2 and gather but I am struggling to get those to work as planned

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a best way to accomplish this, but I can try and show one approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

`ggplot2` likes to work with long form data, so the first step is reshaping the data frame so there's one observation per row. In the example below I make a column for replicate number, but you could drop this since its not actually used here. Next, summarise the data to get the values you're interested in plotting (means for each cell/dilution pair). Last, we make a plot.

Hope this helps!

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


df <- structure(list(Dilution = c(10, 40, 160, 640, 2560, 10240, 40960, 
                                  163840), A2T2_R1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 102, 100, 99, 99), A2T2_R2 = c(1, 
                                                                                                  1, 1, 1, 101, 101, 92, 97), X293T_R1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 98, 97, 
                                                                                                                                           98, 99), X2093T_R2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 98, 97, 98, 98), TZMbl_R1 = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            1, 1, 36, 80, 97, 98, 99), TZMbl_R2 = c(1, 1, 1, 33, 78, 99, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    93, 100)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Dilution = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "collector")), A2T2.R1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector")), `A2T2.R2 X29` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "collector")), `3T.R1 X29` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "collector")), `3T.R2 TZM` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector")), bl.R1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector")), TZMbl.R2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  # ggplot prefers longer data 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Dilution,
               names_to = c('cell','rep'),
               values_to = 'value',
               names_sep = '_') %>%
  # add mean and standard deviations
  group_by(cell, Dilution) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value)) %>%
  # Create a plot
  ggplot(aes(x = Dilution, y = mean, color = cell)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd,
                    ymax = mean + sd))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cell'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Seth, Thanks for the help that did work! I was just wondering if you'd mind explaining the first part if you have time. For example the collector collector double

Comment: Everything in `structure(...)` is the output from `dput`, and its just a way to share the data for others to reproduce. In your actual work that data frame is probably coming from some other source, an imported CSV or something. Try `dput(<data object>)` and you'll see it makes something you can easily copy and paste to a message board like SO. It includes the values from the data frame and also details about each variable, like the `class`.